# what's wrong with web.py? SystemError: error return without exception set

Tags: python, web.py

when uploading a file with web.py, there's a exception `" SystemError: error return without exception set"` raised.

here's traceback

```
    ...
      File "../web/template.py", line 882, in __call__
       return BaseTemplate.__call__(self, *a, **kw)
      File "../web/template.py", line 809, in __call__
       return self.t(*a, **kw)
      File "", line 193, in __template__
      File "../web/webapi.py", line 276, in input
       out = rawinput(_method)
      File "../web/webapi.py", line 249, in rawinput
       a = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=fp, environ=e, keep_blank_values=1)
      File "../python2.7/cgi.py", line 508, in __init__
       self.read_multi(environ, keep_blank_values, strict_parsing)
      File "../python2.7/cgi.py", line 632, in read_multi
       environ, keep_blank_values, strict_parsing)
      File "../python2.7/cgi.py", line 510, in __init__
       self.read_single()
      File "../python2.7/cgi.py", line 647, in read_single
       self.read_lines()
      File "../python2.7/cgi.py", line 669, in read_lines
       self.read_lines_to_outerboundary()
      File "../python2.7/cgi.py", line 697, in read_lines_to_outerboundary
       line = self.fp.readline(1
         
        
        
        
        """

       def POST(self):
        x = web.input(myfile= {})
        return x.myfile.file.read()
```

Comment: That is not a complete traceback; can you edit and show us more?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I'd switch to WSGI anyway, its faster and easy to use. Do you get that error when running the built in webserver?